# Here maps sdk V3.3 not working on android 7

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using HereMaps SDK for a project, I can initialize the map engine without any problems on old Android devices running older version than Android 7

But when I try to run my apk on an Android 7 device I get missing libraries

HereMaps SDK version is 3.3, it's using an AAR file.

I've analyzed the generated APK if it's missing any libraries but everything seems to be in place.

Here is the error exception thrown from the SDK initialization

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.nokia.maps.av.a(EngineError.java:27)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:370)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:346)
    at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:129)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5491)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1583)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6217)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Cannot initialize MapEngine: MISSING_LIBRARIES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I'm using a GIF library that caused a conflict with HERE Maps SDK on Android 7, it's called `GIFImageView`

Answer (score 1):

I added below code in ***Build Gradle*** and it works fine for me in android 7 (**Nougat**)

```
splits {
  abi {
         enable true
         reset()
         include 'armeabi-v7a'
         universalApk false
      }
 }
```